# How do I find integer solutions to $23x+31y=29$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

How do I find integer solutions to $23x+31y=29$?

I feel like the Euclidean algorithm should be the approach but that seems to be failing me. I did figure out that $4k23=3k31$ for any integer $k$ which I have no idea what that means for this problem but it seems like it's somehow an issue that makes this problem impossible.

Edit: I messed up my arithmetic doing the Euclidean algorithm a bunch of times the same exact way. That's why it didn't work and I couldn't find the solution.

Comment: I have no idea what $4k23=3k31$ means _at all_ ...

Comment: ... though, actually, what is true is that $4k\cdot 23 + k = 3k\cdot 31$, which may be what you intended to write, and is directly relevant here.

Comment: You can always solve for $23x + 31 y = 1$ and multiply by $29$ but you can do it more easily.  $29 = 31 - 2$ and $31= 23+8$ and $23 = 3*8-1$ so $29 = 31 - 2(3*8 - 23) = 31 - 2(3(31-23) - 23)= -5*31 + 8*23$

Answer (score 6):

The extended Euclidean algorithm will give you $m$ and $n$ such that
$$ 23m+31n=1 $$
Now multiply that by $29$.

Comment: And then to find the general solution, note that $23m + 31n = 0$ has solution $m = 31k$, $n = -23k$; so a similar argument to a standard argument from linear algebra would show the general solution to $23m + 31n = 29$ would be $m = m_0 + 31k$, $n = n_0 - 23k$.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I ran into trouble using the Euclidean algorithm for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

$29 = 31 -2$

$31 = 23 + 8$

$23 = 3*8 - 1$

So $29 = 31 - 2(3*8 - 23) = 31 -2(3(31 - 23) - 23) = 31 - 6*31 + 6*23 + 2*23 = 8*23-5*31$

of $29 = 23 + 6$.

$23 = 31 - 8$

$31 = 4*8 - 1$

$29 = 23 + 6(4*(31-23) - 31) = -23*23 + 18*31$

etc.

Once you get one you can cat all the rest with $29 = 31(x -23) + 23(y + 31)$.

$29 = -23*23 + 18*31 = 8*23 - 5*31 = 39*23 - 28*31$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing you figured out is $23 \cdot-4 + 31\cdot 3 = 1$.
$$
29(23 \cdot (-4) + 31 \cdot 3) = 29\\
23((-4) \cdot 29) + 31(3 \cdot 29) = 29\\
$$
This one should be obvious:
$$
23 \cdot 31 + 31 \cdot (-23) = 0\\
n(23 \cdot 31 + 31 \cdot (-23)) = n\cdot 0 = 0\\
23(31n) + 31(-23n) = 0\\
$$

Now we can add these resulting equations together.
$$23(-4 \cdot 29 + 31\cdot n) + 31(3 \cdot 29 - 23n) = 29\\
23(31n - 126) + 31(87 - 23n) = 29\\
$$

If you want to be a little fancier, let $m = n - 4$, so $n = m + 4$.
$$23(31(m+4) - 116) + 31(87 - 23(m+4)) = 29\\
23(31m +8) + 31(-5 - 23m) = 29\\
$$

So your solutions are $x=31m+8$ and $y = -5 - 23m$, parameterized over all $m$.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone. Turns out I made the same arithmetic mistakes a bunch of time repeatedly and that's why I thought the Euclidean algorithm wasn't working. This was the last question on a final exam I had been working on for three hours so I somehow got it in my head that I was approaching the problem wrong when I had exactly the right method.